# Replace first few lines with first few lines from other file

Tags: linux, sed

I am working on Linux. I have 2 files - file1.dat and file2.dat.

```
cat file1.dat
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and for file2:

```
cat file2.dat
1a
2a
3a
4a
5a
6a
7a
8a
9a
10a
```

I want to replace first 4 lines from file1.dat with first 3 lines from file2.dat. So my output would be following

```
cat file1.dat
1a
2a
3a
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried following input:

```
sed -i.bak '1,4d;3r file2.dat' file1.dat
```

But with this input I have following output:

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

How should I modify input command? I tried various combinations.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question neatly mentions the required output given an input and portrays your effort in the form of your try with `sed`. Kudos, and have a nice time here `:-)`. Now you can accept an answer that deems fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is your friend

**Script**

```
# awk 'NR==FNR && FNR<=3 || NR>FNR && FNR>4' file2 file1
```

**Output**

```
1a
2a
3a
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Tips**

- NR - Total number of records processed
- FNR - Total number of records processed but resets when reading a new file.
- When a condition evaluates to true and no extra commands are given,`awk` just prints.

  ---

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Following `awk` may also help you in same, tested codes in `GNU awk`.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR<4{print;next} FNR>4 && FNR!=NR' file2.dat file1.dat
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR==4{nextfile} FNR==NR{print;next} FNR>4 && FNR!=NR' file2.dat file1.dat
OR
awk 'FNR==NR{if(FNR==4){nextfile};print;next}  FNR>4 && FNR!=NR' file2.dat file1.dat
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Using `awk` and `head` and `tail` command's combinations here.

```
awk 'FNR==1{system("head -n3 file2.dat");next} 1' <(tail -n +4 file1.dat)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `GNU sed`

```
$ sed '3q' f2 | sed -e '3r /dev/stdin' -e '1,4d' f1
1a
2a
3a
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

- `sed '3q' f2` gives the first three lines from second file
- `-e '3r /dev/stdin'` use stdin data
- `-e '1,4d'` delete required lines
- order is important - first `r` then `d`

For small number of lines, you can also use

```
sed -e '3R f2' -e '3R f2' -e '3R f2' -e '1,4d' f1
```

`R` command reads one line at a time

With GNU coreutils, this would probably be better for all/most scenarios

```
head -n3 f2; tail -n +5 f1
```

Comment: Good explanation `:-)`. But I don't think using `head -n3 f2` has any significant advantage.

Comment: yeah agree ... and if it becomes significant enough, better to use awk or head+tail combo..