# Replace text in a file with a replacement string that contain both real newlines and literal \n

Tags: sed, busybox

How replace text in a file with a replacement string that contain both real newlines and literal \n?

Example that doesn't work:

```
replacement=$(printf "ABC\\nDEF\nGHI\n")
sed -i "s#%PLACEHOLDER%#${replacement}#" FILE.txt
```

It should work only with component included in busybox.

Comment: are you trying to replace part of line or entire line? as far as I know, you cannot have real newlines in `s` command.. only `\n` depending on implementation... to replace entire line, you should use `r` command to add contents from a file (depending on implementation, you could use stdin as well) and then delete the placeholder line..

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775458/using-sed-or-awk-or-a-tool-from-a-fresh-debian-9-install-how-to-do-text-appendi/49775871#49775871 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382204/replace-first-few-lines-with-first-few-lines-from-other-file/48382359#48382359 for examples of `r` command

Comment: I want to replace an entire single line with multiple lines, but these replacement lines must come from a subshell (there is a recursive function here) and preserve the newlines as they are.
The %PLACEHOLDER% text is here because the line to be replaced may be at a different position.

Comment: I have seen that sed break really easily even when quoted, is there another command that accept a string with any possible character ( including spaces and / )?
I have seen awk is more powerfull but it is really hard to understand.

Comment: see the linked Q&As... the `r` command is best suited for these purposes... it adds contents from a file (or stdin) as is without any complaint...

Comment: Ok, now I understand 'r' is inside the parameter of sed.

Comment: This works for me:
sed -i '/%PLACEHOLDER%/r REPL.txt' FILE.txt
sed -i 's/%PLACEHOLDER%//' FILE.txt